# I cannot make the CQL parameter IN work

Tags: postgresql, cql, geoserver, wms

When using the CQL IN operator in my URL i get no result. If I use **CQL_FILTER=id=229539** the URL is working fine. I really need to specify a list so i tried to use the CQL IN operator with no luck. I tried **CQL_FILTER=id IN (229539)** and **CQL_FILTER=id IN ('229539')**, both not working - why?

Comment: Probably much more suitable for http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had to wrap the name id with double quotes and it worked. I think `id` is a reserved name in GeoServer so this way you can solve the problem. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/373005/9518.

Answer (score 0):

CQL

```
id IN ('229539')
```

should actually be fine, we have such queries and they do work.

What you could do to troubleshoot:

- Make sure that URL correctly encoded. Maybe some of the quotes or brackets get interpreted incorrectly.
- Make sure taht nothing else in the query interacts with your query.
- Make sure you don't request two or more layers.
- Turn on and look into the GeoServer logs. I can't give you the exact pointer, but it is possible to turn on the verbose logging and you'll see how the query is processed (up to SQL). This may give good hints.

If nothing helps, post your metadata (WFS GetCapabilities) and exact URLs you're trying.

You may also want to [ask here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the CQL. The CQL was correct. The problem was the definition of the view used for the request.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW data.yellowgreen AS 
  SELECT 
    markblok.id AS id,
    temp_kvadrats.value,
    st_intersection(markblok.geom, temp_kvadrats.geom) AS geom,
    temp_kvadrats.session_id
FROM data.temp_kvadrats
  JOIN data.markblok ON st_intersects(markblok.geom, temp_kvadrats.geom);
```

The CQL only works with '**markblok.id AS id**' and not with just '**markblok.id**', eventhough a list of the view names the column shows **id** in both cases.